# i get this error Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' has no instance getter 'snit'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

1.What im trying to do is sort the datatable by switching the arrow but i don't understand where the error is coming from

```
class _HomePageState extends State<IA> {
      final columns = [
        "snit",
        "name",
        "order",
        "date",
        "dateidentification",
        "sexe",
        "choix",
        "surchaleur",
        "prix",
        "produit",
        "pere",
        "mere",
        "etat",
        "race",
        "origin",
        "zone"
      ];
      List<DataColumn> getColumns(List<String> columns) => columns
          .map((String column) => DataColumn(
                label: Text(column),
                onSort: onSort,
              ))
          .toList();
    
      int compareString(bool ascending, String value1, String value2) =>
          ascending ? value1.compareTo(value2) : value2.compareTo(value1);
      void onSort(int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
        if (columnIndex == 0) {
          _animaldetails.list.sort((animal1, animal2) =>
              compareString(ascending, animal1.snit, animal2.snit));
        }
        setState(() {
          this.sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
          this.isAscending = ascending;
        });
      }
    
      int sortColumnIndex;
      bool isAscending = false;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
            appBar: AppBar(
              elevation: 0,
              leading: Container(),
              title: Text("Artificial Insemination"),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: DataTable(
                  sortAscending: isAscending,
                  sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
                  columns: getColumns(columns),
                  rows: _animaldetails.list.map((item) {
                    return DataRow(cells: [
                      DataCell(Text(item['snit'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['name'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['order'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['date'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['dateidentification'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['sexe'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['choix'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['surchaleur'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['prix'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['produit'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['pere'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['mere'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['etat'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['race'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['origin'].toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(item['zone'].toString())),
                    ]);
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
```

Comment: `compareString(ascending, animal1.snit, animal2.snit));` Did you mean to use `animal1['snit']` and `animal2['snit']`?

Comment: thanks @jamesdlin your solution worked for me i really appreciate your help i wonder if you can explain to me what i did wrong

Comment: Dart is not JavaScript. `object.member` and `object['member']` are not equivalent.  To lookup elements of a `Map`, you must use `map[key]`, and that's appropriate when keys are known to exist at runtime.  In contrast, `object.member` is used for properties that are known to exist statically.